# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: personal (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table created by this sql command ->
CREATE TABLE messages( id integer primary key autoincrement, senderNum String, messagebody String, label String );

In this Table I have a row having senderNum equal to 123.In order to apply label to it i call method which looks like this ->

```
public void ApplyLabel(String senderNum){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("update messages set label=personal where senderNum=" + senderNum,null);



    }
```

where the variable senderNum have value 123.Now when this method is called it throws error like this ->
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: personal (code 1): , while compiling: update messages set label=personal where senderNum=123

I don't know why it gives this error ??

Comment: try `label='personal'`instead

Comment: @JörnBuitink  But what if  I have value "personal" stored in a variable and i want to use that in the query ??

Comment: @HemantKasat consider this: how is your use of `personal` different from your use of `senderNum`?

Comment: @njzk2  if I have senderNum equal to something like this  AR-607662
then if i select the row having senderNum column value equal to senderNum which have value AR-607662  then it will give same error.

Comment: and once again, this is why people should not be allowed to write SQL queries themselves, and should use the built-in `update` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the string delimiters (**'**) surrounding your string value.
As it's now, you are comparing a column named `label` to another column named `personal`, which doesn't exist.

Try:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("update messages set label='personal' where senderNum=" + senderNum,null);
```

If you want to use a variable, you can concatenate the string like so:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("update messages set label='" + strPersonal + "' where senderNum=" + senderNum,null);
```